# VBA how to speed up the code

Tags: vba

Hey I have the following code written in VBA. It simulates trajectory of asset price (`BS_trajektoria_2` function) and calculate payoff from option, This procedure is repeated `num_of_sim` times to get better ressult (because asset price is random so payoff is random).I use it like this: `barrier_MC(100;100;1;0,05;0,02;0,2;120;365;10000;"call";"UO")`.
How can I speed up this code? I would like to use bigger number of `N` and `num_of_sim` but it takes a long time to compile.

```
Function RandNorm(Optional mean As Double = 0, Optional sd As Double = 1) As Double

Dim r1, r2, s As Double
r1 = Rnd()
If r1 = 0 Then r1 = Rnd()
r2 = Rnd()
s = Sqr(-2 * Log(r1)) * Cos(6.283185307 * r2)
RandNorm = mean + sd * s
End Function

    Function payoff(S_T As Double, K As Double, CallPut As String)
    If CallPut = "call" Then
        omega = 1
    Else: omega = -1
    End If
    
    payoff = WorksheetFunction.Max(omega * (S_T - K), 0)
    
    End Function
    

    Function BS_trajektoria2(S_0 As Double, T As Double, r As Double, q As Double, sigma As Double, N As Long) As Double()
    
    Randomize
    Dim s() As Double
    Dim delta_t As Double
    Dim i As Long
    ReDim s(N)
    Dim rand As Double
    s(0) = S_0
    delta_t = T / N
    
    For i = 1 To N
        s(i) = s(i - 1) * Exp((r - q - 0.5 * sigma ^ 2) * delta_t + sigma * delta_t ^ 0.5 * RandNorm())
    Next i
    
    BS_trajektoria2 = s
    End Function
    
    
    
    Function barrier_MC(S_0 As Double, K As Double, T As Double, r As Double, q As Double, sigma As Double, _
                            B As Double, N As Long, num_of_sim As Long, CallPut As String, BarType As String) As Double
    
    Dim max_value As Double
    Dim suma_wyplat As Double
    Dim wyplata As Double
    Dim i As Long
    Dim s() As Double
    suma_wyplat = 0
    
    If (BarType = "DO" Or BarType = "DI") And B > S_0 Then
        MsgBox "Too high barrier!"
        Exit Function
    ElseIf (BarType = "UO" Or BarType = "UI") And B < S_0 Then
        MsgBox "Too low barrier"
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    With WorksheetFunction
    For i = 1 To num_of_sim
        Randomize
        s = BS_trajektoria2(S_0, T, r, q, sigma, N)
        max_value = .Max(s)
        If max_value >= B Then
            wyplata = 0
        Else
            wyplata = payoff(s(N), K, CallPut)
        End If
        suma_wyplat = suma_wyplat + wyplata
    Next i
    End With
    barrier_MC = Exp(-r * T) * suma_wyplat / num_of_sim
    End Function
    
    Sub test3()
    MsgBox barrier_MC(100, 100, 1, 0.05, 0.02, 0.2, 120, 1000, 10000, "call", "UO")
    End Sub
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please use Option Explit at the start of each module.  Also take a look at the fantastic and free Rubberduck addin for VBA.  The indenter and code inspections will help your code a lot.  Given the above my inclination would be to move from pure VBA to a library in C#.  http://pragmateek.com/extend-your-vba-code-with-c-vb-net-or-ccli/

Comment: What does the code do?

Comment: @pacmaninbw it simulates trajectory of asset price and calculate payoff from option, This procedure is repeated num_of_sim times to get better ressult

Comment: Please state that in the question.

Comment: Ok I add some information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is how much speed improvement you expect. What I would do:

I'd analyze `RandNorm` for this is a user function that you call 10M times that really influences runtime. Considering that `rnd` provides pseudo-random numbers it might even be unappropriate but it's your choice.

Minor improvements can be achieved by replacing

```
   For i = 1 To N
         s(i) = s(i - 1) * Exp((r - q - 0.5 * sigma ^ 2) * delta_t + sigma * delta_t ^ 0.5 * RandNorm())
   Next i
```

with

```
 fact1 = Exp((r - q - 0.5 * sigma ^ 2) * delta_t
 fact2 = sigma * delta_t ^ 0.5
 For i = 1 To N
     s(i) = s(i - 1) * fact1 + fact2 * RandNorm())
 Next i
```

for most factors are constant within the loop so you don't need to calculate them so many times.

Also you can check max value in this loop like

```
If s(i) > sMax Then sMax = s(i)
```

and return sMax somehow to `barrier_MC` so you don't need to call `WorksheetFunction.Max` on an array of 1K doubles 10K times.

I'd also rework `payoff` to eliminate the need of `WorksheetFunction.Max` (10K times) like

```
payoff = omega * (S_T - K)
If CallPut = "call" Then
    If payoff > 0 Then payoff = 0
Else
    If payoff < 0 Then payoff = 0
End If
```

I'd also consider replacing "Call" `string` parameter with a `Long` constant so you can replace 10K string comparisons with `Long` comparisons.

You `Randomize` before calling `BS_trajektoria2` and within `BS_trajektoria2`.